# Index 2D numpy array by a 2D array of indices without loops

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am looking for a vectorized way to index a `numpy.array` by `numpy.array` of indices.

For example:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0,3,4],
              [5,6,0],
              [0,1,9]])

inds = np.array([[0,1],
                 [1,2],
                 [0,2]])
```

I want to build a new array, such that every row(i) in that array is a row(i) of array `a`, indexed by row of array inds(i). My desired output is:

```
array([[ 0.,  3.],   # a[0][:,[0,1]]
       [ 6.,  0.],   # a[1][:,[1,2]] 
       [ 0.,  9.]])  # a[2][:,[0,2]]
```

I can achieve this with a loop:

```
def loop_way(my_array, my_indices):
    new_array = np.empty(my_indices.shape)
    for i in xrange(len(my_indices)):
        new_array[i, :] = my_array[i][:, my_indices[i]]
    return new_array
```

But I am looking for a pure vectorized solution.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When using arrays of indices to index another array, the shape of each index array should match the shape of the *output* array.  You want the column indices to match `inds`, and you want the row indices to match the row of the output, something like:

```
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 2]])
```

You can just use a single column of the above, due to broadcasting, so you can use `np.arange(3)[:,None]` is the vertical `arange` because `None` inserts a new axis:

```
>>> np.arange(3)[:, None]
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2]])
```

Finally, together:

```
>>> a[np.arange(3)[:,None], inds]
array([[0, 3],   # a[0,[0,1]]
       [6, 0],   # a[1,[1,2]] 
       [0, 9]])  # a[2,[0,2]]
```

Answer (score 9):

It’s possible, although somewhat non-obvious to do this as follows:

```
>>> a[np.arange(a.shape[0])[:, None], inds]
array([[0, 3],
       [6, 0],
       [0, 9]])
```

The index `np.arange(a.shape[0])` simply indexes the rows to which the array of column indices `inds` applies. Appending `[:, None]` modifies the shape of this array such that its shape is `(a.shape[0], 1)`, i.e. each row index is in a separate row of a 1-column-wide 2D array.

The basic principle is that the number of dimensions in the index arrays must agree, and their shapes must also do so. See documentation for `np.ix_` to get a feel for this.