# top k columns with values in pandas dataframe for every row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like the following:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  7  2  5  2
1  3  3  1  1
2  0  2  6  1
3  3  6  2  9
```

There can be 100s of columns, in the above example I have only shown 4.

I would like to extract top-k columns for each row and their values.

I can get the top-k columns using:

```
pd.DataFrame({n: df.T[column].nlargest(k).index.tolist() for n, column in enumerate(df.T)}).T
```

which, for k=3 gives:

```
   0  1  2
0  A  C  B
1  A  B  C
2  C  B  D
3  D  B  A
```

But what I would like to have is:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  A  7  C  5  B  2
1  A  3  B  3  C  1
2  C  6  B  2  D  1
3  D  9  B  6  A  3
```

Is there a pand(a)oic way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `numpy` solution:

- [`numpy.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) for columns names
- array already sort (thanks [Jeff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42533883/top-k-columns-with-values-in-pandas-dataframe-for-every-row/42534268#comment72205303_42534268)), need [`values by indices`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20103779/2901002)
- [`interweave`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5347065/2901002) for new array
- `DataFrame` constructor

```
k = 3
vals = df.values
arr1 = np.argsort(-vals, axis=1)

a = df.columns[arr1[:,:k]]
b = vals[np.arange(len(df.index))[:,None], arr1][:,:k]

c = np.empty((vals.shape[0], 2 * k), dtype=a.dtype)
c[:,0::2] = a
c[:,1::2] = b
print (c)
[['A' 7 'C' 5 'B' 2]
 ['A' 3 'B' 3 'C' 1]
 ['C' 6 'B' 2 'D' 1]
 ['D' 9 'B' 6 'A' 3]]

df = pd.DataFrame(c)
print (df)
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  A  7  C  5  B  2
1  A  3  B  3  C  1
2  C  6  B  2  D  1
3  D  9  B  6  A  3
```

Comment: this is non nonperformant and the point of nlargest which is a partition sort ; argsort sorts everything

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> def foo(x):
...     r = []
...     for p in zip(list(x.index), list(x)):
...             r.extend(p)
...     return r
... 
>>> pd.DataFrame({n: foo(df.T[row].nlargest(k)) for n, row in enumerate(df.T)}).T
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  A  7  C  5  B  2
1  A  3  B  3  C  1
2  C  6  B  2  D  1
3  D  9  B  6  A  3
```

Or, using list comprehension:

```
>>> def foo(x):
...     return [j for i in zip(list(x.index), list(x)) for j in i]
... 
>>> pd.DataFrame({n: foo(df.T[row].nlargest(k)) for n, row in enumerate(df.T)}).T
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  A  7  C  5  B  2
1  A  3  B  3  C  1
2  C  6  B  2  D  1
3  D  9  B  6  A  3
```

Comment: good solution but the lists and for loop make it quite slow if the number of rows in dataframe are of the order of 10k+

Comment: @AbhishekThakur I added a variant of the same solution using list comprehension, though I don't have any idea about its performance.

Comment: Ahh, it seems that's not the problem. the problem arises when the function is being applied to every row of the pandas dataframe one-by-one :)

Answer (score 1):

This does the job efficiently :  It uses argpartition that found the n biggest in O(n), then sort only them.

```
values=df.values
n,m=df.shape
k=4
I,J=mgrid[:n,:m]
I=I[:,:1]
if k<m: J=(-values).argpartition(k)[:,:k]
values=values[I,J]
names=np.take(df.columns,J)
J2=(-values).argsort()
names=names[I,J2]
values=values[I,J2]
names_and_values=np.empty((n,2*k),object)
names_and_values[:,0::2]=names
names_and_values[:,1::2]=values
result=pd.DataFrame(names_and_values)
```

For

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  A  7  C  5  B  2
1  B  3  A  3  C  1
2  C  6  B  2  D  1
3  D  9  B  6  A  3
```

Comment: this throws the following error:

----> 4 d3=d[I,big3]
    

IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,1) (10,3)

Comment: I don't understand why; I adapt some things for better generality. What numpy version do you use ?

Comment: numpy version is: 1.12.0

Comment: I think the last version work : the problem was that your df  was longer(10) than the exemple(4).

Comment: this is wayyy faster than other methods... for my particular problem which was an extension to my question, it improved performance by 300%!

Comment: I don't think this gives the desired result compared to `nlargest`. It so happened to be the case here.

Comment: @Nickil Maveli : where is the problem ?

Comment: also, its not working if i need the maximum number of columns. eg. k=4

----> 5 big3=(-d).argpartition(k)[:,:k]
ValueError: kth(=4) out of bounds (4)

Comment: Ok, I have adapted for this case.