# summarizing 2 columns into one based on a third index column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe

> ```
>   first_char second_char type
> 1          a           b  1/1
> 2          a           b  0/1
> 3          a           b  0/1
> 4          c           d  1/1
> 5          c           d  0/1
> 6          c           d  0/0
> ```

I would like to combine these columns into one as such:

```
1       bb
2       ab
3       ab
4       dd
5       cd
6       cc
```

The `type` column contains the indeces separated by a forward slash for first_char and second_char columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20104162/2901002) solution for filter by arrays of indices for avoid looping by `apply`:

```
ind = df['type'].str.split('/', expand=True).astype(int).to_numpy()
arr2 = df[['first_char','second_char']].to_numpy()    

df['new'] = arr2[np.arange(ind.shape[0])[:,None], ind].sum(1)
print (df)
  first_char second_char type new
1          a           b  1/1  bb
2          a           b  0/1  ab
3          a           b  0/1  ab
4          c           d  1/1  dd
5          c           d  0/1  cd
6          c           d  0/0  cc
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way using `np.take_along_axis`:

```
s = df["type"].str.split("/", expand=True).astype(int)

df["new"] = np.take_along_axis(df[["first_char","second_char"]].to_numpy(),s.to_numpy(), axis=1).sum(1)

print (df)

  first_char second_char type new
1          a           b  1/1  bb
2          a           b  0/1  ab
3          a           b  0/1  ab
4          c           d  1/1  dd
5          c           d  0/1  cd
6          c           d  0/0  cc
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add the char columns and split the type column and use these values as index for summed chars, like this:

```
df.apply(lambda x: ''.join([(x['first_char']+x['second_char'])[int(number)] for number in x['type'].split('/')]),axis=1)

1    bb
2    ab
3    ab
4    dd
5    cd
6    cc
```