# Sort each row absolute value independent of columns along with column names

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I have a data frame of similar format:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
 'p1': [0, 0, 1, 1, -2],
 'p2': [9, 2, 3, -5, 3],
 'p3': [1, 3, 10, 3, 7],
 'p4': [4, 4, 7, 1, 10]})

    p1  p2  p3  p4
0   0   9   1   4
1   0   2   3   4
2   1   3   10  7
3   1   -5  3   1
4   -2  3   7   10
```

Expected output:

```
top1    top2
p2:9    p4:4
p4:4    p3:3
p3:10   p4:7
p2:-5   p3:3
p4:10   p3:7
```

With a lot of research, I was able to sort and obtain the indices of the sorted array. I was also able to replace the indices with columns. But I am unable to concatenate them with row values.

```
nlargest = 3
order = np.argsort(-df.abs().values, axis=1)[:, :nlargest]
result = pd.DataFrame(df.columns[order], 
                      columns=['top{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, nlargest+1)])

  top1 top2 top3
0   p2   p4   p3
1   p4   p3   p2
2   p3   p4   p2
3   p2   p3   p1
4   p4   p3   p2
```

Using the above method I tried to sort the rows in a different DataFrame and later thought of concatenating them. But I couldn't find the right way to do that. I know this is not an optimal way though.

```
result2 = pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.values, axis=0), index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
result2 = result2.iloc[:, 0:nlargest]
result2.columns = columns=['top{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, nlargest+1)]

   top1  top2  top3
0    -2    -5     1
1     0     2     3
2     0     3     3
3     1     3     7
4     1     9    10
```

Please help me correct the sorting and the shortest way to get the expected format.

Comment: Optimal way means the best performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use for best performance only numpy solution:

```
nlargest = 3
arr = df.to_numpy()
order = np.argsort(-np.abs(arr), axis=1)[:, :nlargest]
print (order)
[[1 3 2]
 [3 2 1]
 [2 3 1]
 [1 2 0]
 [3 2 1]]
```

Idea is change order of original data in numpy array `arr` by `order` array like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20103779/index-2d-numpy-array-by-a-2d-array-of-indices-without-loops) solution:

```
a = arr[np.arange(arr.shape[0])[:, None], order]
print (a)
[[ 9  4  1]
 [ 4  3  2]
 [10  7  3]
 [-5  3  1]
 [10  7  3]]
```

So you can add values converted to strings:

```
result = pd.DataFrame(df.columns[order] + ':' + a.astype(str), 
                      columns=['top{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, nlargest+1)])

print (result)
    top1  top2  top3
0   p2:9  p4:4  p3:1
1   p4:4  p3:3  p2:2
2  p3:10  p4:7  p2:3
3  p2:-5  p3:3  p1:1
4  p4:10  p3:7  p2:3
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort @jezrael

Answer (score 3):

Use, [`DataFrame.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) along with [`DataFrame.lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html):

```
result = result.transform(lambda s: s + ':' + df.lookup(s.index, s).astype(str))
```

---

```
# print(result)
    top1  top2  top3
0   p2:9  p4:4  p3:1
1   p4:4  p3:3  p2:2
2  p3:10  p4:7  p2:3
3  p2:-5  p3:3  p1:1
4  p4:10  p3:7  p2:3
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to create strings we can use `.stack`, `.groupby` and `.cumcount` to grab the top n values.

```
largest_n = 3

s = (
    df.stack()
    .sort_values(ascending=False)
    .groupby(level=0)
    .head(largest_n)
    .reset_index(1)
    .astype(str)
    .agg(":".join, axis=1)
    .to_frame("vals")
)
```

---

```
df1 = (
    (
        s.assign(key=s.groupby(level=0).cumcount() + 1)
        .set_index("key", append=True)
        .unstack()
    )
    .add_prefix("Top_")
    .droplevel(level=0, axis=1)
)
```

---

```
print(df1)

key  Top_1 Top_2 Top_3
0     p2:9  p4:4  p3:1
1     p4:4  p3:3  p2:2
2    p3:10  p4:7  p2:3
3     p3:3  p1:1  p4:1
4    p4:10  p3:7  p2:3
```

Comment: @supreeth2812 no problemo, I'd go with Jezrael's solution as its better for larger datasets and will be quicker than using a lambda

Comment: You were right! @jazrael solution was actually faster and made sense to use it since the data set was huge and had to run it multiple times.