# Change numpy 2d array at the positions descibed in list of lists

Tags: python, numpy

I have numpy M*N array.

```
numpy.random.seed(23)
A = numpy.round(numpy.random.random((4, 10)), 2)

array([[0.59, 0.77, 0.66, 0.56, 0.18, 0.24, 0.51, 0.4 , 0.48, 0.96],
       [0.9 , 0.51, 0.82, 0.83, 0.23, 0.08, 0.47, 0.88, 0.15, 0.23],
       [0.92, 0.13, 0.92, 0.23, 0.62, 0.95, 0.26, 0.45, 0.97, 0.24],
       [0.2 , 0.69, 0.85, 0.45, 0.1 , 0.62, 0.08, 0.05, 0.35, 0.91]])
```

Then I have a list of M lists of indexes:

```
ind = [[1,2], 
       [4,7,8,9], 
       [3,6,7], 
       [4,5,1]]
```

Each list contains indexes of the corresponding row to be nulled, i.e. at row #0: 1th and 2nd elements should be nulled, etc...

And I should obtain:

```
array([[0.59, 0.  , 0.  , 0.56, 0.18, 0.24, 0.51, 0.4 , 0.48, 0.96],
       [0.9 , 0.51, 0.82, 0.83, 0.  , 0.08, 0.47, 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.92, 0.13, 0.92, 0.  , 0.62, 0.95, 0.  , 0.  , 0.97, 0.24],
       [0.2 , 0.  , 0.85, 0.45, 0.  , 0.  , 0.08, 0.05, 0.35, 0.91]])
```

The forehead solution is:

```
for i in range(len(ind)):
    A[i, ind[i]] = 0
```

But, you know, it's too slow. Is it possible to have "vectorized" solution?

Comment: Since the column lists vary in length, easy 'vectorizung' isn't possible.   I can imagine expanding the row indices with `repeat` to match `np.hstack(ind)` and doing one assignment, but can't promise a speedup.

Comment: @hpaulj I thought about numpy.vectorize, but it does not work natively with 2d arrays ))

Comment: [`np.vectorize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) has a *Note* about expecting performance improvements. Can the part that creates *ind* be changed or is it fixed?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20103779/index-2d-numpy-array-by-a-2d-array-of-indices-without-loops might help but without jagged ind lengths

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny yes... it's always different

Comment: That's not what I meant. Can the code be changed that is creating the list?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny no

Comment: Converting *ind* into a vectorizable format will be slower than iterating over it once. Zipping *A,ind* is 2x faster in my benchmarks: `for i,j in zip(A, ind): i[j] = 0`

Comment: @IliyaFiks why not? How are you generating these indices in the first place?

Comment: If you're willing to make some compromise in how these values are actually generated, this task becomes trivial. Otherwise, you're stuck with the "forehead" solution because there's just no other way to use ragged arrays. Also, the "forehead" solution *does* still take advantage of advanced indexing, FWIW.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question in the post,

> Is it possible to have "vectorized" solution?

No. It is not possible to take advantage of vectorization because your `ind` list is ragged. However, depending on how you acquire these index values, changing that process slightly makes the task trivial:

```py
rows = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
cols = [1, 2, 4, 7, 8, 9, 3, 6, 7, 4, 5, 1]

A[rows, cols] = 0
```

If you can produce your indices this way *in the first place*, then you're golden.

Again, as others have mentioned, this information (the rows and columns) is already present in your indices. Depending on how they were generated (which I suggest you share as an edit to the body of the question) in the first place (either calculated or read from a file, whatever) you *should* theoretically be able to generate your indices in the appropriate format in the first place, thereby negating the necessity for your "forehead" workaround or having to transform the indices into a numpy-compatible format after the fact altogether.

So, TL;DR -- if you can generate your indices in the format I've shown above *in the first place*, do so. If not, then there's no point in using anything other than the "forehead" solution.

Comment: All this information must be available anyway when the irregular list is created. With `numpy` arrays, this would also use less memory. I disagree that this answer is not useful for future readers. Similar questions are asked frequently.

Comment: "All this information..." -- exactly, hence why I wanted to actually put it in answer form, since OP seems to be missing the forest for the trees here. I'll redact the bit about it not being useful.

Comment: I timed this appraoch - with the creation of the full `row/col`, and found that it is a bit slower - for this particular combination of shapes.  I expect relative speeds to very.

Comment: The idea is that if OP has control of the process of generating these indices in the first place then the benefit will be greater, presumably. Obviously transforming *what OP currently has* into something numpy likes will not benefit them, *but* if they can simply make their indices "numpy-compatible" in the first place, then that likely will net OP appreciable performance.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. No, unfortunately, I can't do it. But, I think I can try to generate indexes in "mask" format. And then try to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Your iterative solution:

```
In [78]: %%timeit 
    ...: for i in range(len(ind)):
    ...:     A[i, ind[i]] = 0
34.4 µs ± 118 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

The alternative that I suggested in a comment:

```
In [79]: d=np.arange(4).repeat([len(i) for i in ind])    
In [80]: d
Out[80]: array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3])    
In [81]: A[d,np.hstack(ind)]
Out[81]: array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
    
In [83]: %%timeit
    ...: d=np.arange(4).repeat([len(i) for i in ind])
    ...: A[d,np.hstack(ind)] = 0
37.1 µs ± 71.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

This alternative is a bit slower.  However the relative speeds will vary for real world cases, depending on the `shape` of `A`, and the number of indices in a `ind`.

Comment: thank you for your solution. In my case, typicall size of A is 10000 * 3000.
So....
`
%time
for i, indexes in enumerate(indexes_to_zero):
    A[i, indexes] = 0<br/>

CPU times: total: 4.09 s
Wall time: 4.09 s
`
And
`
%%time
d = numpy.arange(A.shape[0]).repeat([len(i) for i in indexes_to_zero])
A[d, numpy.hstack(indexes_to_zero)] = 0
CPU times: total: 4.61 s
Wall time: 4.6 s
`