# numpy: how to avoid looping over array to sum over one dimension while indexing from another array?

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have 2 arrays A and B where the values in A correspond to the index in the first dimension of B

```
A = np.array([[ 0,  3,  4], 
              [ 5,  6,  0],
              [ 0,  1,  9],
              [11, 12, 13]])

B = np.array([[0, 1, 1],
              [1, 2, 0],
              [0, 2, 3],
              [3, 3, 3],
              [0, 3, 1],
              [3, 1, 1],
              [1, 1, 0]])
```

For each row j of B, I want to sum the elements in A that correspond to A[B[j, i], i], to get a new array of shape 7. I can do it with loops like this:

```
output_array = np.zeros(B.shape[0])
for i in range(A.shape[1]):
    for j in range(B.shape[0]):
        output_array[j] += A[B[j, i], i]
```

which would give me as output_array

```
array([ 6., 10., 14., 36., 12., 17., 15.])
```

Is there any **fast and efficient** way to do the same for large arrays without having to loop?

The closest answer I could find here was [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20103779/index-2d-numpy-array-by-a-2d-array-of-indices-without-loops), but I need to actually do a sum inside one of the loop and I wasn't able to extend to my case.

Comment: How large are the actual arrays?

Comment: A would be in the range of 2000 x 500 and B 20000 x 500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it simple as follows:

```py
def numpy_solution(A, B):
    return A[B, np.arange(A.shape[1])].sum(axis=1)
```

However, this creates a temporary array of the same size as B `(20000, 500)`, which degrades performance.

To get around this, and this may seem counterintuitive, you can actually make it faster by keeping one loop.

```py
def keep_i_loop(A, B):
    output_array = np.zeros(B.shape[0], dtype=A.dtype)
    for i in range(A.shape[1]):
        output_array += A[B[:, i], i]
    return output_array
```

Furthermore, in terms of speed, this is a calculation that [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) is better at.

```py
import numba


@numba.njit("int32[:](int32[:,:],int32[:,:])")
def numba_solution(A, B):
    output_array = np.zeros(B.shape[0], dtype=A.dtype)
    # Note that I have swapped i and j loops.
    for j in range(B.shape[0]):
        for i in range(A.shape[1]):
            output_array[j] += A[B[j, i], i]
    return output_array
```

Here is the benchmark code and results.

```py
import timeit
import numpy as np


def baseline(A, B):
    output_array = np.zeros(B.shape[0])
    for i in range(A.shape[1]):
        for j in range(B.shape[0]):
            output_array[j] += A[B[j, i], i]
    return output_array


def benchmark():
    rng = np.random.default_rng(0)
    A = rng.integers(0, 1000, size=(2000, 500), dtype=np.int32)
    B = rng.integers(0, 2000, size=(20000, 500), dtype=np.int32)

    expected = baseline(A, B)
    assert np.all(expected == numpy_solution(A, B))
    assert np.all(expected == keep_i_loop(A, B))
    assert np.all(expected == numba_solution(A, B))

    n = 100
    r = timeit.timeit(lambda: numpy_solution(A, B), number=n) / n
    print(f"numpy_solution: {r * 1000:.0f} ms")

    r = timeit.timeit(lambda: keep_i_loop(A, B), number=n) / n
    print(f"keep_i_loop: {r * 1000:.0f} ms")

    r = timeit.timeit(lambda: numba_solution(A, B), number=n) / n
    print(f"numba_solution: {r * 1000:.0f} ms")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    benchmark()
```

```
numpy_solution: 66 ms
keep_i_loop: 46 ms
numba_solution: 15 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

Using fancy indexing:

```
out = A[B,
  np.repeat(np.arange(A.shape[1])[None],
            B.shape[0], axis=0)
 ].sum(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
array([ 6, 10, 14, 36, 12, 17, 15])
```

This works by using arrays indices of the shape of B to index A, thus maintaining the shape of B as output.

Intermediates:

```
np.repeat(np.arange(A.shape[1])[None], B.shape[0], axis=0)

array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2],
       [0, 1, 2]])


out = A[B,
  np.repeat(np.arange(A.shape[1])[None],
            B.shape[0], axis=0)
 ]

array([[ 0,  6,  0],
       [ 5,  1,  4],
       [ 0,  1, 13],
       [11, 12, 13],
       [ 0, 12,  0],
       [11,  6,  0],
       [ 5,  6,  4]])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Create a column index array for A using np.arange and np.tile
column_index_array = np.tile(np.arange(A.shape[1]), B.shape[0]).reshape(B.shape)

# Create a row index array for A using np.arange and broadcasting
row_index_array = np.arange(B.shape[0])[:, None]

# Iterate B's indices using row and column indices to fetch corresponding values from A
output_array = A[B, column_index_array].sum(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

With short [`np.trace`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.trace.html#numpy.trace) routine to sum along diagonals of the "index" array:

```
out_arr = np.trace(A[B], axis1=1, axis2=2)
```

---

```
array([ 6, 10, 14, 36, 12, 17, 15])
```

Comment: Smart idea but won't this create a humongous intermediate array?